# AJAX request is cancelled by Chrome when issued from within the extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am doing a simple AJAX request within Chrome extension, but Chrome cancels my request each time. I did specify necessary cross-origin permissions in the manifest file. The server also allows cross-origin requests, i.e I am able to execute my ajax script within a normal browser window. I also tried doing the old way via XMLHttpRequest - the result is the same. What am I missing?

The full JS code loaded by extension is below (getUmsIdByEmail_ is the function):

```
var AssumeIdentityController = function () {
  this.button_ = document.getElementById('button');
  this.customer_email_ = document.getElementById('emailfield');
  this.addListeners_();
};

AssumeIdentityController.prototype = {
  /**
   * A cached reference to the button element.
   *
   * @type {Element}
   * @private
   */
  button_: null,

  /**
   * A cached reference to the select element.
   *
   * @type {Element}
   * @private
   */
  timeframe_: null,
  customer_email_: null,

  /**
   * Adds event listeners to the button in order to capture a user's click, and
   * perform some action in response.
   *
   * @private
   */
  addListeners_: function () {
    this.button_.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick_.bind(this));
  },

  /**
   * Given a string, return milliseconds since epoch. If the string isn't
   * valid, returns undefined.
   *
   * @param {string} timeframe One of 'hour', 'day', 'week', '4weeks', or
   *     'forever'.
   * @returns {number} Milliseconds since epoch.
   * @private
   */
  
  getUmsIdByEmail_: function(email){
    console.log('attempting to fetch');

    var opts = {
      method: 'GET',      
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    fetch('<SERVER_WITH_THE_RESOURCE>', opts).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (body) {
       console.log(body)
    });

 
  },


  // getTokenByUms_: function(umsId) {

  //   return token
  // }

 
  /**
   * Handle a success/failure callback from the `browsingData` API methods,
   * updating the UI appropriately.
   *
   * @private
   */
  handleCallback_: function () {
    var success = document.createElement('div');
    success.classList.add('overlay');
    success.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
    success.textContent = 'Data has been cleared.';
    document.body.appendChild(success);

    setTimeout(function() { success.classList.add('visible'); }, 10);
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (close === false)
        success.classList.remove('visible');
      else
        window.close();
    }, 4000);
  },

  /**
   * When a user clicks the button, this method is called: it reads the current
   * state of `timeframe_` in order to pull a timeframe, then calls the clearing
   * method with appropriate arguments.
   *
   * @private
   */
  handleClick_: function () {

     this.getUmsIdByEmail_('sd');
    if (this.customer_email_  !== undefined)
    {
        
      
    // var token = getTokenByUms(umsId);
    // if(replacePreprodToken(token))
    // {
    //   print('successfully logged in. Refreshing the page');
    // }
    // else 
    // {
    //   print('Can't log in. Please try again later'); 
    // }

    }


 
    // }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.log('dom content loaded');
  window.PC = new AssumeIdentityController();
});
```

Permissions in manifest look like this:

```
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "browsingData","declarativeContent","storage","https://*/","http://*/"
  ],
  ...
```

Comment: Where and how is this script loaded? Content script or a popup script? What exact steps are you performing?

Comment: @wOxxOm it's a popup script, I load it within HTML page, no special directives anywhere else. The ajax call is triggered by click, so i just click on the button. Another detail: I was able to get 200 response by placing breakpoints and executing step-by-step. It looks like a bug in Chrome extensions to me.

Comment: If the request is canceled when you close the popup then it's the intended behavior: the popup runs only when shown and stops when hidden.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for letting me know. I'll check again, but I don't think I closed the pop-up, so I don't expect the request to get cancelled. In any case, is this the bug tracking board for Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/ ?